# UIScrollview scrollRectToVisible is not moving with animation when i am using gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 3 views in a scrollview and I have given swipe gesture to these subviews.
On swipe I am rotating that view using (CATransform3DMakeRotation) and also scrolling my scrollview at the same time to give a page fold effect. 
It is working as expected, but subview is not detecting swipe every time.

After implementing

```
– gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
```

and

```
– gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:
```

subviews are detecting swipe every time, but now the scroll animation is not working.
Now it is scrolling(without animation) at the end of view rotation animation.

Code I have used

```
    //Animation Code
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^(void){

        CATransform3D _3Dt = CATransform3DIdentity;
        _3Dt = CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0f, 7.5f, 0.0f), CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, 0));
        _3Dt.m34 = 0.0015f;

        v.layer.transform = _3Dt;
        //[scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scroll.contentSize.width-300, 0)];
        [scroll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(300, 10, 300, scroll.frame.size.height) animated:NO];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){}];


and

    //GestureRecognizer Delegate

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return YES;
}
```

Please suggest something

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[yourGesture setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
```

**Edit**

also change the animated property to YES

```
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(300, 10, 300, scroll.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
```

Comment: animate YES is using its own pre defined animation duration. I dont want that.

Comment: then use setContentOffset instead of scrollRectToVisible in the animation block , i think it should work, why ave you commented it

Comment: even contentOffset is giving same result